# WMI: Get the list of Installed Softwares

Tags: windows, wmi

I need to get the list of installed softwares on remote Windows hosts using `wmi` calls. I have tried using `Win32_Product` and `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms` Classes.

Advantage of using `Win32_Product` is that, it displays all the softwares installed on the machine, but it is very very slow and does not work on more than 90% hosts (giving errors like- `NTSTATUS: NT code 0xc002001b - NT code 0xc002001b`). On the other hand, `Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms` is much quicker and works pretty well on most of the hosts, but misses plenty of softwares.

Is there any other Win32 Class that could do the same efficiently?

Comment: Also worth bearing in mind is that using Win32_Product can have some odd side-effects: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974524. This article may be useful though: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/13/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software.aspx

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use wmic.

Example:

```
wmic product get name,version /format:csv

wmic /node:localhost /output:d:\programlist.htm product
get name,version /format:htable.xsl

wmic product get name,version

wmic softwareelement get name,version

wmic softwarefeature get name,version

wmic wmic:root\cli>/output:c:\ProgramList.txt product get name,version
```

Or you can do it like the "Add/Remove Programs", reading all uninstall registry keys:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

On 64 bit Windows, remember to also check:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

To returns a list of all software installed on a computer, whether or not by Windows-Installer:

```
Const HKLM = &H80000002 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE 
strComputer = "." 
strKey = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strEntry1a = "DisplayName" 
strEntry1b = "QuietDisplayName" 
strEntry2 = "InstallDate" 
strEntry3 = "VersionMajor" 
strEntry4 = "VersionMinor" 
strEntry5 = "EstimatedSize" 

Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & _ 
 "/root/default:StdRegProv") 
objReg.EnumKey HKLM, strKey, arrSubkeys 
WScript.Echo "Installed Applications" & VbCrLf 
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
  intRet1 = objReg.GetStringValue(HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry1a, strValue1) 
  If intRet1 <> 0 Then 
    objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
     strEntry1b, strValue1 
  End If 
  If strValue1 <> "" Then 
    WScript.Echo VbCrLf & "Display Name: " & strValue1 
  End If 
  objReg.GetStringValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry2, strValue2 
  If strValue2 <> "" Then 
    WScript.Echo "Install Date: " & strValue2 
  End If 
  objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry3, intValue3 
  objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry4, intValue4 
  If intValue3 <> "" Then 
     WScript.Echo "Version: " & intValue3 & "." & intValue4 
  End If 
  objReg.GetDWORDValue HKLM, strKey & strSubkey, _ 
   strEntry5, intValue5 
  If intValue5 <> "" Then 
    WScript.Echo "Estimated Size: " & Round(intValue5/1024, 3) & " megabytes" 
  End If 
Next
```

Comment: `wmic product` is just an alias for the `Win32_Product` class, isn't it? All of those `wmic` commands are just aliases to regular classes. `wmic product` in fact calls `wmic path Win32_Product get *`. The OP is asking for an alternative to this.

Comment: @Dawid Ferenczy Rogožan: Yes, but WMIC (Windows Management Interface Command) is an optimization of WMI for batch scripts. It's faster.

Comment: `wmic alias list brief` lists the wmi class aliases.

Answer (score 1):

The encoded version in c# that is based on the readings in the system registry windows.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace SoftwareInventory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //!!!!! Must be launched with a domain administrator user!!!!!
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            StringBuilder sbOutFile = new StringBuilder();
            Console.WriteLine("DisplayName;IdentifyingNumber");
            sbOutFile.AppendLine("Machine;DisplayName;Version");

            //Retrieve machine name from the file :File_In/collectionMachines.txt
            //string[] lines = new string[] { "NameMachine" };
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"File_In/collectionMachines.txt");
            foreach (var machine in lines)
            {
                //Retrieve the list of installed programs for each extrapolated machine name
                var registry_key = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machine).OpenSubKey(registry_key))
                {
                    foreach (string subkey_name in key.GetSubKeyNames())
                    {
                        using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(subkey_name))
                        {
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"));
                            //Console.WriteLine(subkey.GetValue("IdentifyingNumber"));
                            if (subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                                sbOutFile.AppendLine(string.Format("{0};{1};{2}", machine, subkey.GetValue("DisplayName"), subkey.GetValue("Version")));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //CSV file creation
            var fileOutName = string.Format(@"File_Out\{0}_{1}.csv", "Software_Inventory", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mmssfff"));
            using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileOutName))
            {

                file.WriteLine(sbOutFile.ToString());
            }
            //Press enter to continue 
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue !");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, `get-package` in powershell 5.1 will list all the installed software.  It's a compiled cmdlet, so I'm not sure how it works, if it uses wmi or the registry.  Powershell 7 unfortunately doesn't support the msi or programs providers.

Win32_SoftwareElement seems to be msi installs only.

I believe Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms requires the sccm client, 'Configuration Manager Client'.