# Getting Program Installed List of Remote Computers

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find a way to get the GUID of every program installed on about 150 computers. I was thinking I could create a login script that would run a script and save the result to a share folder on a server. The script will run but the file is empty. If I run the script inside manually it works. Below are the scripts I created. one is at batch file and the other is powershell.

**Batch File**

```
wmic product get > \\svr\Public\Diagnostics\%computername%-installed-programs.txt
```

**Powershell**

```
$properties = "identifyingnumber","name","vendor","version"
$ComputerName = $env:computername
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Product -Property $properties |             
Select -Property $properties |             
Export-Csv -Path \\svr\Public\Diagnostics\$ComputerName-Installed-Programs.csv -Encoding Unicode -NoTypeInformation
```

The the user does have permission to write to the specified location.

Any idea why this isnt working? I am open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: No idea!  I swapped out for a local path, and it worked on my computer here.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131413/wmi-get-the-list-of-installed-softwares) but to answer the question in `WMIC` use:

`wmic /node:server` for remote machines.

In Powershell, `Get-WMIObject` has the `-ComputerName` parameter allowing you to run the command against a remote computer.

Try: `Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName RemoteMachine101`

Comment: I have tried that before but I am getting an error saying that the RPC server is unavailable. I have a bit of an issue with running the script in this fashion. My biggest problem is that I have to type in each name of every computer I want to inventory. If I create a login or startup script and have it store online I can assign it to a particular OU and have each user or computer in that group run the script and save the results.

Comment: RPC server is unavailable is a pretty common error when dealing with remote computers.  Make sure your Powershell console is running as `Administrator` and your account has Administrative privileges on the target computer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem and this is what I did.

First, I added a GPO that to the computer configuration that would accept WMI-In. That fixed the "RPC server is unavailable" response.

Second, I ran an IP scan using Angry IP of all available nodes. Then I exported the list to a CSV file and then modified it so that only the IP addresses showed. I then saved it as a text file.

Next, I created a PowerShell script. The script pulls the IP addresses from the txt file I previously generated. The script will run each IP address and save the results of each IP in a sperate file. Below is the script:

```
$IPAddress = Get-Content Z:\Installed-Software\ip-addresses.txt
foreach($ComputerName in $IPAddress) { 
echo $ComputerName
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select-Object Name, IdentifyingNumber | Export-Csv C:\Installed-Software\$ComputerName-installed-programs.csv }
```

You could run the scan on an entire subnet but I chose to scan or available nodes and run the script only on those nodes. Since it takes a minute or 2 to generate the results I figured by eliminating all offline nodes it would save some time.

Hope this helps someone. Special thank you to user4317867 for the push.

Answer (score 0):

Win32_product produces some unwanted results via endpoint and network bandwidth. When called MSI files perform an integrity and compatibility check with architecture. This can result in slower speeds and decreased pipe. A GREAT alternative is the uninstall registry- but if you don't feel up to parsing strings and paths just use the     Gwmi win32_addremoveprograms -computer  | select *

I know this is not an answer to the RPC error but definitely worth noting when using "product" vs alternatives. Good luck!